# DateFormat should appear as dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: json, jqgrid-asp.net

My date format in `Jqgrid` appears as `NaN/NaN/NaN` .I want to make it as `dd/mm/yyyy`. What are the necessary corrections i want to make for it.

My code is

```
jQuery("#jsonmap").jqGrid
    (
    {
        url: 'Edit.aspx',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype:'GET',

        align:"center",
        colNames: ['empID', 'empName','Dob'],
        colModel: [{
                name: 'empID',
                index: 'empID',
                width: 150,
                key:true,
                editable: false,
                align:"center",
                editoptions: {
                readonly: true,
                sorttype:'int',

                search:true,
                size: 100
            }},                
            {
                name: 'empName',
                index: 'empName',
                width: 150,
                sortable:true,
                align: "center",
                editable: true,
                size: 100
              },


            {
                name: 'Dob',
                index: 'Dob',

                align: "center",

                sorttype:'Dob',
                formatter: 'date',
                 datefmt: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                 editable: true,
                  edittype: 'text',
                  editrules: { required: true, date: true },
                 formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} 




      },
```

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` == Not-a-Number... Most likely you're doing a wrong calulationor div-by-zero somewhere?